# how to ignore the seconds ToShortTimeString

Tags: c#

My datetime is showing me the seconds eventhough i have put as this
`TimeSlotFrom = Value.ToShortTimeString();`

I can view it from my laptop only `HH:mm`. However when read from your client's pc, it show it as `HH:mm:ss`.

does it relates to the time format used in my client's pc? How do i handle this to just show HH:mm ?

Comment: read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx

Comment: Short answer.. What is the culture setting for your **laptop** say for de-DE culture, it is `HH:mm`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use `Value.ToString("HH:mm")` to always get the same format, because ToShortTimeString uses the format defined on the PCs culture.

Answer (score 5):

From MSDN:
`DateTime.ToShortTimeString` Method

> The value of the current DateTime
>   object is formatted using the pattern
>   defined by the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern
>   property associated with the current
>   thread culture.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortTimePattern
```

> Your applications are recommended to
>   set the short time pattern to the
>   exact value of interest, instead of
>   attempting to have the time separator
>   replaced. For example, to obtain the
>   pattern h-mm-ss, the application
>   should set "h-mm-ss" specifically.

Or the simplest is to use this instead

```
TimeSlotFrom = Value.ToString("HH:mm tt")
```

Comment: This is a misleading answer. HH is 24h format hours and tt is AM\PM
You may want to change your solution to "HH:mm" or "h:mm tt"

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the standard format used by ToShortTimeString() is changed in the client machine. Check what the current format is set to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Standard short time output: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
Console.WriteLine("Standard short time format: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
```

You can either change the value of ShortTimePattern to what you need (but be careful as this affects all ToShortTimeString() output on the current thread):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "h:mm:ss tt";

Console.WriteLine("Modified short time format: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
Console.WriteLine("Modified short time output: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

If this is not an option, format the time by specifying the format as shown in the other answers above (date.ToString("h:mm tt)).

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/ is a good reference on string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between machines is most likely occurring because the string returned from `ToShortTimeString()` is culture sensitive.  It reflects the time pattern defined by the current culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object.

If you would like to force a specific format I would suggest being more explicit.  For example:

```
var TimeSlotFrom = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is misleading answer. hh is 12h format hours and missing the tt for AM\PM
You may want to change your solution to "HH:mm" or "h:mm tt"

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
TimeSlotFrom = Value.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

Short time pattern: "h:mm tt"
Short time string:  "3:02 AM"

Just give "h:mm" if you don't want AM/PM

Comment: ToShortTimeString have no parameters.